# Rich snippets on Google's ccTLD domains

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, internationalization

I've implemented rich snippets for review on my site and everything works fine when my site pops out in Google search results when using google.com. The problem is that I can not see any stars in result for my site when I search through google.de or google.fr.

Here is an example:

- keyword: "mighty knight", domain: google.com
  https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=might+knight
  → Review stars appear for kongregate.com
- keyword: "mighty knight", domain: google.com.mt
  https://www.google.com.mt/?gws_rd=ssl#q=might+knight
  → Review stars does not appear for kongregate.com

(Note: nokongregate.com is not my domain, nor the game, it was just an example.)

Comment: Review rich snippets are not automatic or guaranteed. Google has ever changing criteria for rich snippets. It is not uncommon for them to appear for a while, disappear for a while, and then reappear. As well, for sites registered with a ccTLD, how rich snippets are handled changes.

Comment: I *do* see the rich snippet on google.com, google.de and google.com.mt.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty here is that when Google assesses rich snippets it decided algorithmically if the rich snippets are appropriate based on the ccTLD being used to access Google. IE: Your rich snippets may be deemed appropriate for the main google.com site but are not considered as important, or rather not of as much value to users in Germany (google.com.de) or Malta (google.com.mt). There is nothing really you can do to force it as there is no guarantee that Google will show your rich snippets in search results and your snippets can be shown for some keywords and then later no longer show for those same keywords.